# Using R for 3 variable stacked barplot

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Currently, I have this code:

```
### Uses the library ggplot2###
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

### Reads in the CSV file to be plotted ###
plot <- read.csv("C:/Users/dam203/Desktop/Ongoing_Projects/output-1.csv")

### Makes R recognize that the X-axis has been pre-sorted so that GGPLOT2 does not sort alphabetically. ###
plot$Date <- factor(plot$Date, levels = plot$Date)

### Plots the Graph ###
ggplot(plot[which(plot$F.Sym.Onset>0),], aes(x=Date, y=F.Sym.Onset)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) + ggtitle("Epidemic Pertussis Case Curve")
```

This is a small sample of what data from a CSV file looks like.  However, there are more columns and rows in the actual CSV file.  Date, C.Sym.Onset, F.Sym.Onset, D.Sym.Onset are the only columns I am interested in right now.:

```
Date    C.Sym.Onset   F.Sym.Onset   D.Sym.Onset     Temp
6-Jan        2              1                        47
7-Jan        1              3            2           57
8-Jan                                    1           54
9-Jan                                                58
10-Jan       1                                       59
```

As the code is above, it currently ignores dates without F.Sym.Onset and plots the # of cases on a given date organized according to the chart, rather than ggplots default alphabetical ordering.

My question is, how do I make it so that I can plot C.Sym.onset, F.Sym.Onset, and D.Sym.Onset on a vertical stacked bar chart?

This is a copy of a chart my script currently produces from a CSV file with full data:

[RPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS718.png)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code and I was able to create a stacked bar-plot using melt with the following code:

```
### Uses the library ggplot2###
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

### Reads in the CSV file to be plotted ###
ModelOutput <- read.csv("C:/Users/dam203/Desktop/Ongoing_Projects/output-3.csv")

### Creates a new dataframe using only variables needed to plot the PECurve. ###
PECurve <- data.frame("Date" = ModelOutput$Date, 
                "C.Sym.Onset" = ModelOutput$C.Sym.Onset,
                "F.Sym.Onset" = ModelOutput$F.Sym.Onset,
                "D.Sym.Onset" = ModelOutput$D.Sym.Onset)

### Removes rows where value is 'NA' in C.Sym.Onset, F.Sym.Onset, and D.Sym.Onset. ###
PECurve <- PECurve[!with(PECurve,is.na(C.Sym.Onset)& is.na(F.Sym.Onset)&  is.na(D.Sym.Onset)),]

### Makes R recognize that the X-axis has been pre-sorted so that GGPLOT2 does not sort alphabetically. ###
PECurve$Date <- factor(PECurve$Date, levels = PECurve$Date)

### Plots according to Day of Symptom Onset ###
df <- melt(PECurve, .measure.vars=.(C.Sym.Onset, F.Sym.Onset, D.Sym.Onset))
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

An example of a final plot from the CSV looked like this:

[GGPlot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK3bp.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date(), by = 'days'),
                 x = sample(c(1:3, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
                 y = sample(c(1:3, NA), 6, replace = TRUE),
                 z = sample(c(1:3, NA), 6, replace = TRUE))
longdf <- gather(df, var, value, -Date)

ggplot(longdf, aes(value, fill = var)) +
  geom_bar()
```

You need to gather your columns into a single variable. Then you can plot them as a stacked bar chart by specifying the fill with the var.